# The console application code I wrote in Dev-C ++ runs smoothly in the compiler but seems missing when running the .exe application?

Tags: console-application, exe, dev-c++

I just started learning C++. I made a small console application using the scanf function, when I say compile and run in DevC++ environment, it opens smoothly (even I tried it in the online C++ compiler, there is no problem in the console) but when I close and run the program with the .exe extension I compiled, the last part is missing. It does not appear on the console after a certain location and the console turns off directly. What error, what warning, why might it be, and how can I fix it?

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    
    char isminiz[15];
    char soyisminiz[15];
    char yasiniz[3];
    
    printf ("Isminizi yaziniz: ");
    scanf("%s",isminiz);
    printf ("Soyisminizi yaziniz: ");
    scanf ("%s",soyisminiz);
    printf ("Yasiniz: ");
    scanf("%s",yasiniz);
    
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Just to clarify, does it work if you run it when you are already in a cmd box?

Comment: Please do not remove the content from your question. This allows other users to benefit from it. If you found a solution, instead consider leaving the question as is and post your solution as an answer to your own question. This will help future users facing the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

Add a `system("pause");` before the `return 0;`.
There is no break point between the last printf() functions and the return. Also, remove the `#include <iostream>` since it is for C++, and you are not using it (your code is C).

Comment: The same problem still continues. There is no problem in the compiler, the exe file closes immediately. 
Do you want to try? https://mega.nz/#!dmIgjQSb!CwZrHPxjCAFJXQeps-qwrm6xOsDWtkdDLeF9LLEW7Wo

Answer (score 0):

Since you are trying to do it on C.
Use [getchar()](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/getchar/) before the return function.

```cpp
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {

    printf ("Uyari: Turkce karakter kullanmayiniz ve sorulari tek kelime ile cevaplandiriniz.\n\n");

    char isminiz[15];
    char soyisminiz[15];
    char yasiniz[3];
    char mutlu[15];
    char sanat[30];
    char fb[20];
    char kim[20];

    printf ("Isminizi yaziniz: ");
    scanf("%s",isminiz);
    printf ("Soyisminizi yaziniz: ");
    scanf ("%s",soyisminiz);
    printf ("Yasiniz: ");
    scanf("%s",yasiniz);
    printf ("Mutluluk nedir: ");
    scanf("%s",mutlu);
    printf ("Peki sanat nedir desek: ");
    scanf("%s",sanat);
    printf ("Fb nin uykusu gelmis midir: ");
    scanf("%s",fb);
    printf ("Isim: %s - Soyisim: %s \n",isminiz,soyisminiz);
    printf ("Mutluluk: %s\n",mutlu);
    printf ("Sanat: %s\n",sanat);
    printf ("Gelmis mi: %s\n\n",fb);
    printf ("Fb seni cok seviyor dostum hayirli geceler :) \n");
    printf("Devam etmek için herhangi bir tuşa basın\n");

    getchar();

    return 0;
}
```

I have compiled and executed it on Linux terminal and the window will remain open. Basically the [getchar()](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/getchar/) function will wait for the user to press a key. This works like system.pause() except that it is for C and it will only close when the user will press a button. I don't know what it was asking for in the input so I entered strings since %s was the required input in scanf.

Comment: If my answer solved your problem. I would appreciate if you mark it as helpful so that others may also benefit from it. Thank you and welcome.